# Loops for Unit Root Test

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to compute some unit root tests on a data generating process.
I already split the sample in 100 single samples, but how can I do a unit root test on all of them and store the results in another table?
I tried several ways but can't find a solution...

Here is my code:

```
le = 100;

px = Table[0, {100}];

Do[e = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], le];

 p = Table[0, {le}];

 Do[p[[i]] = p[[i - 1]] + e[[i]];, {i, 2, Length[p]}];

 px[[ii]] = p;, {ii, 1, 100}]

s = Split[px]
```

(it works up to here, so I have this hundred subsamples, but I have no idea how to perform the hundred corresponding unit-root tests; doing it by hand can't be the solution or ^^..)

Here my attempt:

```
pt = Table[0, {100}];

Do[UnitRootTest[px[[t]], {t, 1, 100}]

px[[t]]=pt
```

Comment: does that `RandomReal` work? Its not a documented usage (likely you mean `RandomVariate` )?

Comment: `UnitRootTest/@px` seems to be all you need..

Comment: @george2079 `RandomVariate` superseded `RandomReal` and `RandomInteger` for distributions in M8. For distributions that existed prior to that time it should still work but `RandomVariate` is certainly encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you need:

```
UnitRootTest /@ (Accumulate[#] - #[[1]] & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {le, le}])
```

It does exactly the same thing as your original block of code, but is much shorter, and eliminates the need for multiple `Do` loops.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked out well!